# First instance of sound is delayed

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

I'm using the following code to play a simple clicking sound when tapping a button.

```
import AudioToolbox

private var clickSound: SystemSoundID!

func createSound(soundName: String) -> SystemSoundID {
    var id: SystemSoundID = 0

    let url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), soundName, "wav", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &id)

    return id
}

    //Load click sound.
    clickSound = createSound("ButtonClick")
```

This works, but he first time I tap a button, the sound is delayed a bit.  All subsequent button taps result in the sound playing immediately.  It leads me to believe that the sound is not loaded until the first time it's played.

Is there any way to get rid of this delay?

Comment: how many different sound you need to play in your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known issue.

You can play a small silent sound bite during startup. That way the sound routines will be loaded and ready to perform when you want them to.

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SILENCE" ofType:@"WAV"]], &alarm); 
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (alarm);
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I did and it works perfectly.